# Revert a Checkbox value in the ChkBoxGroup_Click event

Tags: vba, checkbox, click, revert

I have multiple checkboxes created, and I would like to prompt the users when they CLICK on the checkbox.  They can only change the value of the check box with the correct PIN.  If they enter a incorrect PIN, the checkbox will revert back to it's original value.
However every time when it try to revert the checkbox value, it seems like it recursively calling the ChkBoxGroup_Click() event until a correct password is entered.

```
Private Sub ChkBoxGroup_Click()
    Dim ValidatePIN_RNT As Boolean

    ValidatePIN_RNT = ValidatePIN()
    If Not ValidatePIN_RNT Then
        ChkBoxGroup.Value = Not ChkBoxGroup.Value
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before `ChkBoxGroup.Value = Not ChkBoxGroup.Value` and change it back to `TRUE` after the change has been made. BTW, what would happen if you were to remove the `Exit Sub` line from your code?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I added the Application.EnableEvents = False before the ChkBoxGroup.Value but it still doesn't work. (still going recursively until a correct PIN is entered.) And removing the Exit Sub doesn't change anything.

Comment: It still bypassed the "End if" jump directly to the ChkBoxGroup_change() event then go to the ChkBoxGroup_Click event. 

Private Sub ChkBoxGroup_Change()
'do nothing.
 'If nRevert = True Then ChkBoxGroup.Value = Not ChkBoxGroup.Value
    'Debug.Print "ChkBoxGroup_Change"
End Sub

Private Sub ChkBoxGroup_Click()
    Dim ValidatePIN_RNT As Boolean
    
    ValidatePIN_RNT = ValidatePIN()
    If Not ValidatePIN_RNT Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ChkBoxGroup.Value = Not ChkBoxGroup.Value
        'Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Comment: No. Removing (or adding) the `Exit Sub` doesn't change anything because it's at the end of the sub. However, what kind of animal is the `ChkBoxGroup`? If it's a group of related CheckBoxes it's `Value` can't be set. Instead, you should capture the change of any one of the CheckBoxes in the group and return its value to the opposite of what the user made it. Consider using `Application.Undo` but do use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to ensure that the change made by your macro doesn't trigger the same event again.

Answer (score 0):

It also work now! I found a post from excelforum.com that the application.enable events setting controls ONLY Workbook and Worksheet events.  And from the post it suggested to use global variable.  It worked for me!!